# how to convert HLS to RTMP with DISCONTINUITY tag

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, http-live-streaming

We have software that produces concatenated HLS files. This concatenation is basically just playlist manipulation. We replace some parts of the manifest by other parts. To make the HLS valid we add a #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag before and after the change:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:4.0000,
http://host/stream/1
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.0000,
http://host/stream/2
#EXTINF:4.0000,
http://host/stream/3
#EXTINF:4.0000,
http://host/stream/4
#EXTINF:4.0000,
http://host/stream/5
#EXTINF:4.0000,
http://host/stream/6
#EXTINF:0.2917,
http://host/stream/7
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:4.0000,
http://host/stream/8
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

In an HTML5 player above manifest will play just fine. Everything is in sync, audio and video play.

Now, when i try and convert above to an rtmp format and stream this to a rtmp endpoint it works, but it stalls after about 4 seconds, than it continues missing 4 seconds, and runs fine after that.

Basically, it plays part 1, skips 2, and continues with 3.

I've checked the logs for ffmpeg which repeat:

```
[flv @ 0x7fa696837c00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3924, current: 0; changing to 3924. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0x7fa696837c00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3924, current: 23; changing to 3924. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0x7fa696837c00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3924, current: 46; changing to 3924. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

After the DTS warnings ffmpeg reports that it dropped 95 frames:

```
frame=  102 fps= 22 q=28.0 size=     181kB time=00:00:04.34 bitrate= 341.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=95 speed=0.958x
```

This of course makes, sense, when i check with ffprobe i can see that the PTS isn't aligned (which is expected):

```
frame|pkt_pts_time=5.316667|pkt_dts_time=5.316667|pict_type=B
frame|pkt_pts_time=5.358333|pkt_dts_time=5.358333|pict_type=B
frame|pkt_pts_time=5.400000|pkt_dts_time=1.400000|pict_type=P
frame|pkt_pts_time=5.441667|pkt_dts_time=1.441667|pict_type=P
frame|pkt_pts_time=1.483333|pkt_dts_time=1.483333|pict_type=I
frame|pkt_pts_time=1.525000|pkt_dts_time=1.525000|pict_type=B
frame|pkt_pts_time=1.566667|pkt_dts_time=1.566667|pict_type=B
```

The 95frames, is exactly the number of frames with a PKT_PTS_TIME (and DTS) in the past.

the ffmpeg command i use to create the RTMP stream is:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -re -i http://host/manifest -c:v libx264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -c:a aac -ar 44100 -r 24 -f flv rtmp://domain/some/rtmp/endpoint
```

What i'm looking for is a way to convert the HLS to a valid RTMP, without it skipping the frames with a PTS in the past. I would like it to just regenerate the PTS:
Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to regenerate the PTS/DTS timestamps in it's output file?

Comment: I've patched ffmpeg myself using the patch from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5419 it's not an official patch but it does work. Would be better if there is a more stable solution

Comment: i really wanted that 

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support for discontinuitys in RTMP.

Comment: thanks, but i'm looking for a solution to convert the 'invalid' PTS/DTS timestamps to valid ones, any change that's possible with ffmpeg? (ignore whatever is incoming and just generate new timestamps)